# How to find the point where user clicked inside the OnMouseLeftButtonDown method?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

i am overriding the OnMouseLeftButtonDown function and inside i want to know the point where user clicked?

any ideas on how this can be achieved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`GetPosition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190492%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of MouseEventArgs to get a Point object with that coordinates.